# change field after or before a regex

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

i'm trying to change the field after email with regex.

```
demo@example.com:john

desired output demo@example.com|john
```

here is my script , but i get empty data whats the problem??

```
awk '{sub(/\(.*@.*\):/,"|")}'
```

Comment: You don't want to change a field; you want the same fields with a different field *delimiter*.

Comment: The "get empty data" problem is you're missing the `print` statement to produce output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Seems OP needs to cover mail id always and then want to change colon, so following may help on this case then.

```
echo "demo:@example.com:john" | sed 's/\(.*\.com\):\(.*\)/\1|\2/'
```

---

Simple `sed`

```
sed 's/:/|/' Input_file
```

OR

```
echo "demo@example.com:john" | sed 's/:/|/'
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
echo "demo@example.com:john" | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\1|\2/'
```

***solution 3rd:***

```
echo "demo@example.com:john" | awk '{sub(/:/,"|")} 1'
```

Comment: what if the data have  demo:@example.com:john
will become 2 field and that i told you i need a regex after email .com: (.*@.*\):

Comment: and of course `tr ':' '|'`. @DrJay if you have cases like you just asked about in your comment then obviously they should be present in your question, don't wait until people have answered and THEN tell us the sample input you posted isn't very good at representing your real input. Since you've already accepted an answer it's unlikely you'll get other answers now.

Comment: @DrJay, check my edited answer now and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally replace the field separator based on whether the value before the delimiter matches the regex, here is an Awk option:

```
$ echo -e "demo@example.com:john\nnot an email:dave" |
      awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="|" } NF == 2 && $1 ~ /^.*@.*$/ { $1=$1 } 1'
demo@example.com|john
not an email:jacob
```